# R Boolean network. wrong input to reconstructNetwork function

Tags: r, graph, boolean, bioinformatics

R has a package called BoolNet, that has a function called reconstructNetwork.

Maybe someone with a better understanding of R data formats can help me use this. This is kind of an out-there question; just in case someone is looking to try a new R package.

I think I am following the documentation

Documentaion for BoolNet's reconstructNetwork function:

```
reconstructNetwork(measurements, 
                   method = c("bestfit", "reveal"), 
                   maxK = 5, 
                   readableFunctions = FALSE,
                   allSolutions = FALSE)

"measurements must be a list of matrices, each corresponding to one time series. 
Each row of these matrices contains measurements for one gene on a time line, 
i. e. column i+1 contains the successor states of column i. 
The genes must be the same for all matrices in the list."
```

So I think my matrix should look like

```
 t0 t1
[[1 0]
 [0 0]
 ...
 [0 1]]
```

My actual data is 8 possible states, and 2 time points. So an 8x2 matrix.

```
A <- matrix( c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0), nrow = 8, ncol = 2)

B <- matrix( c(0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0), nrow = 8, ncol = 2)

C <- matrix( c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0), nrow = 8, ncol = 2)

list_mats = list(A,B,C)

reconstructNetwork(list_mats, method = "reveal", maxK = 3, readableFunctions = TRUE, allSolutions = FALSE))
```

But the my results are saying I have 8 units instead of 3 (my A,B and C). I've tried transposing each matrix. I am using this function because I want to run the [REVEAL algorithm](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=069E0518C0DE2DC1C4FACCA473C6B413?doi=10.1.1.8.5380&rep=rep1&type=pdf) to infer a Boolean network out of the transition table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the data to be formatted by state, not by gene:

```
state1 <- data.frame(t1=c(0,0,0),t2=c(1,0,0))
state2 <- data.frame(t1=c(0,0,1),t2=c(1,0,0))
state3 <- data.frame(t1=c(0,1,0),t2=c(1,1,1))
state4 <- data.frame(t1=c(0,1,1),t2=c(1,1,1))

list_mats = list(state1,state2,state3,state4)

reconstructNetwork(list_mats, method = "reveal", maxK = 3, readableFunctions = TRUE, allSolutions = FALSE)
```

I only did the first 4 of 8 states, but you get the idea.